# How to report on Multiselect field frequency

Tags: reporting, multi-select

When selecting fields in a Multiselect - every combination is counted as a single value in a report.

There are some [ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BriL) to update that behviour, but I wonder, if anyone has a workaround, where I can create a report (frequency report) on a Mutliselect field.

Frequency - meaning the number of each value occurrence BUT not in a combination - As a single atomic option.

Answer (score 3):

Via reports - no.

The only way I've managed to do it is via code - I do a describe on the picklist values for the field, put them in a map with a 0 as the initial value, run a query for all records you want to evaluate, and loop through the results incrementing the value for each item in the map for each value in the MVP field for that record.

Clunky I know, but if the number of records is not too high it does work...for instance, if I had a field called Cancelation_Reason__c on Account, this would tell me how many times each value in the picklist was referenced by an account...

```
Map<String, Integer> MVPCount = new Map <String,Integer>();

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResultd = Account.Cancelation_Reason__c.getDescribe();
for (Schema.PicklistEntry p: fieldResultd.getPicklistValues() ) {
MVPCount.put(p.getValue(),0);
}

For (Account a: [SELECT Id, Cancelation_Reason__c from Account WHERE Cancelation_Reason__c !=null]) {
String []  mvpsplit = a.Cancelation_Reason__c.split(';');
for (String s :  mvpsplit) {
    if (MVPCount.ContainsKey(s) ) {
        MVPCount.put(s, MVPCount.get(s) + 1);
    }
}
}    
    system.debug(MVPCount);
```

Comment: mind to share code example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand what you mean. But you could wrap the frequency logic you want into a formula field then report on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the frequency, Why not do this-

1. Make a summary report for your sObject, and create a grouping based on your multi-select picklist
2. Run your report and  hide details.

This gives you a frequency of each combination at a birds eye view. If you want a visual, make an extra -large graph

Comment: I want the frequency of the single instances of each occurrence. Not the combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I can see this being achieved without the use of code would be to make a formula.

IF(Contains(MyMultiPickList__c, "X;"), 1, 0)

this will return a value of 1 if the value. After this you run a summary report or matrix report (to show a bunch of tallies) to tally all of your values and will give you a running total. Keep in mind this may cause some issues if you are dealing with a ton of records and by this I mean a million plus... formula are not saved via the record and are always generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

we just released a new appexchange app that may be able to assist you in getting the counts by each occurrence:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B53brEAB

Its a completely free app and 100% salesforce native.